# Change the same id on html

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change the same id by pressing a button

I have the same id on my html, but only the first updates, when I press the button with code `document.getElementById('gold').innerHTML = gold;`

## Example

```js
var gold = 0;
document.getElementById('gold').innerHTML = gold;

function goldMaker() {
  gold = gold + 1;
  document.getElementById('gold').innerHTML = gold;
}
```

```html
Gold: <span id="gold">0</span> 
<p>
  Money: <span id="gold">0</span>
</p>

<button onclick="goldMaker(1)">Make gold/money</button>
```

Comment: if you have changed it then you can't use the original id

Comment: No, and it is invalid using same id on 2 or more elements

Comment: id cannot repeat. here you have same for both spans

Comment: if you like reflect changes on both span use class

Comment: any specific reason to not to use `class` ?

Comment: use class instead. An ID shouldn't be repeated. Thus the name ID, identifier, unique and so on ...

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `id` on more than one element. These must be unique. Use a `class` instead and retrieve the proper element with an index or add additional classes to make the query more intelligent.

Below, I have a simple increment function to grab the second element and increment its value.

```js
function goldMaker(index) {
  incrementValue('gold', index, 1);
}

function incrementValue(className, index, amount) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[index];
  element.innerHTML = (parseInt(element.innerHTML, 10) || 0) + amount;
}
```

```html
Gold: <span class="gold">0</span><br />
Money: <span class="gold">0</span><br />
<button onclick="goldMaker(1)">Make gold/money</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

ID must be unique in whole page so it always returns only the first one occurence.

You could look for duplicate IDs if they are in different containers, e.g.

```
gold1 = $('#rings #gold');
gold2 = $('#necklaces #gold');
```

However this is NOT recommendable practice!

Comment: `getElementById` is a method that appears on the `document` object, but not one that appears on every HTML element. That code won't work.

Comment: @Quentin Right, I did not realize it's possible only in jQuery and not in vanilla JS - it's because I don't use that. I've changed it to jQuery code.

Comment: Jquery can't do anything vanilla JS can't. You could probably do it with `querySelector()` rather than `getElementById()`. But you shouldn't - better to fix the html and use classes.

Comment: Using classes is definitely better, but sometimes you just need to work with poorly designed page that contains duplicate ids and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function goldMaker() {
  gold = gold + 1;
  //  document.getElementById('gold').innerHTML = gold;
 var ele= document.getElementsByTagName("span") ;
 console.log(ele);
    for(var i=0; i<ele.length; i++)
    {
      ele[i].innerHTML = gold;
    }
}
```

Use this method on button click, though its not recommended

Comment: This will technically work, but will update all spans on the page *regardless* of `id`.

Comment: yeah, that's why this is not recommended with jquery this would have been different. $("span[id='gold']")